# Postgres - Optimize for reads on large, tightly related datasets

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-schema

I am currently working on building a postgres database for a project. I have a few different models that inherit the same fields.

```
class Animal
  int legs

class Cat < Animal
  int tail_length

class Snake < Animal
  bool is_venomous
```

**I need to optimize for fast reads for datasets of up to a million Animals with the majority being Cats. I am worried that these relations could hurt performance with too many joins on these large datasets.**

I would like to be able to fetch an Animal by id but also be able to fetch all Cats or Snakes.

I see two different ways of doing this:

**Foreign Keys with Materialized Views**

```
Animal                           Cat
+---------------+----------+     +--------------+-------------+
| primary key   | id       |     | foreign key  | animal_id   |
+---------------+----------+     +--------------+-------------+
| int           | legs     |     | int          | tail_length |
+---------------+----------+     +--------------+-------------+
```

Then have a materialized view do the join for Cats before the query to retrieve all cats

*OR*

**Postgres DB inheritance**

```
Animal                           Cat INHERITS (Animal);
+---------------+----------+     +--------------+-------------+
| primary key   | id       |     | int          | legs        |
+---------------+----------+     +--------------+-------------+
| int           | legs     |     | int          | tail_length |
+---------------+----------+     +--------------+-------------+
```

This allows the query select * from Animal to grab all animals and select * from Cats to grab all cats.

**What is the best way to optimize for reads on large datasets that are inherited and tightly related in postgres?**

EDIT: Also how much time would it take to index the materialized views following a write?

Comment: A milion records is not large enough to think about performance ahead of time. With proper configuration postgres will be able to handle 1 milion records with any sane schema.

Comment: BTW if your has a number of irregular properties - it may be better to use something like EAV or a simple JSON/XML storage.

Comment: I would suggest to think about model correctness and to optimize it later. PostgreSQL optimization for tightly related datasets is "CLUSTER My_Table USING My_Index" , it orders physical storage by index but this operation requires exclusive lock. Million records is a trivial table size, it will processed in memory if you will configure it, if you will add index on foreign key then there is nothing to optimize with small table with trivial queries by index.

Comment: Thanks guys. The more I read about inheritance the more horror stories I find and materialized views are brand new in postgres. I don't think I will use either initially and I will cross this bridge when my db speed slows.